# Review Audit with no option to flag, downvote or comment

Tags: bug, review-audits

I came across a [late answer review](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/33104) for a Community Wiki post.

It was (to me) obvious it was an audit. However, I did not have any options to do anything *about* the post. My options were to Skip, or to select No Action Needed. The former does nothing to prove I knew how to handle the post, the latter leads to a "You were naughty" message (I tried both).

What I wanted to do but was not given the options for, was to flag, comment, or vote down. None of these options were available.

This is most likely a bug due to this being a deleted CW post.

---

[Reaces](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/276684/reaces) ran into this problem as well and managed to create a screenshot:

[image]

---

> *Added by DragonLord to avoid posting a non-answer to the question*
>
> ---
>
> I can reproduce this bug with a review audit item that was a spam post I had already flagged. While this isn't exactly the same as the issue originally described by the OP, I suspect this problem has the same root cause.
>
> *Click image to view full size*
> [image: Spam post review audit already flagged]
>
> I was able to downvote it, but [downvoting isn't the correct way to respond to a spam post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193916/why-shouldnt-i-downvote-spam-that-ive-already-flagged), so this is a crude workaround at best. Can someone address this?

Comment: No screenshot? ....Nice... ;)

Comment: Yup, I fully see the irony here..

Comment: @Bart: Fixed, see edit.

Comment: @DragonLordtheFiery: I wasn't even given the flag dialog, the whole link was missing.

Comment: @DragonLordtheFiery: still, it would make *some* sense; if I had flagged that post before and a related bug (since fixed) caused the flag option to not be present then that'd explain the bug perfectly.