# Disallow premature down-voting

Tags: feature-request, down-votes, fastest-gun

Recently I've witnessed some very trigger-happy down-voting on answers that had only just been posted and were still in the process of being edited. In one case I had just posted an answer with a couple of minor mistakes and within the 30 seconds it took me to edit the answer into shape I'd received two down-votes (with no explanatory comments of course). I've seen this happen to other people today too, so I don't think it's just me feeling victimized. The result of this knee-jerk down-voting is an otherwise useful answer which might as well be deleted, since no one is going to take much notice of an answer that already has a -2 rep.

So, a possible feature-request: disallow down-voting (or perhaps any voting?) until, say, 30 seconds after an answer has been posted or last edited ?

Comment: Oh great - a down-vote and no explanation already - sometimes I wonder why I bother...

Comment: So you got downvotes for answers with mistakes? And the problem is?

Comment: @Bart: I have no problem with down-votes for genuine errors, but down-voting a brand new answer while it is still being edited *and not even bothering to leave an explanatory comment* seems counter-productive, as the down-votes are unlikely to ever be removed once the typo has been fixed, and the answer is then worthless.

Comment: But in that case the downvotes are not premature. At most the answer is. And your real problem in that case is that users do not revise their votes once they have cast them.

Comment: @PaulR Why are you worried about the lack of comments if you already know that your answer has mistakes and what they are?  If you didn't know what the problem was *then* it would be something to concern you.

Comment: @Servy: if the down-voter at least leaves a comment you can then respond appropriately, e.g. note that the error has been corrected, and the down-voter can then remove their down-vote if they choose to, otherwise it remains indefinitely.

Comment: @PaulR And if you just waited to post your answer until it was ready to be judged you wouldn't need to do that.  In any case, you're apparently only concerned with a comment so that you know who downvoted you, not so that you can actually use the comment to improve the content.  That's not really helping your case.

Comment: @WillNess I'm sure you've already supported this?: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179093/get-rid-of-the-question-ban-on-meta-suspend-actively-harmful-users-manually And I'm sure that the OP will be fine.

Comment: @WillNess: thanks - point taken - I shall think twice before making any further contributions to meta.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: @PaulR I wish someone would warn me ahead of time instead of feeding me false information about how "downvotes on meta are just to express disagreement, nothing more". But all the same, the truth has come out about this site. And btw the mintruth has erased my comment to you here. He who controls the past controls the future.

Comment: @WillNess: yes I noticed that one of your comments had been deleted already - it all seems rather bizarre and Orwellian, and I don't really get what the agenda here is, other than maintaining some kind of clique who control meta, exclude outsiders and stifle dissent. It seems totally inconsistent with the general StackExchange ethos and I've never seen anything like it on other SE boards. It will be interestingly to see how long this com

Comment: @PaulR and I replied to you, and that my reply was deleted as well. I am being denied the speech itself.

Comment: @Bart thanks for that link BTW, I didn't know about it. Going into Meta is so much negative for me, I do it very rarely.

Comment: @PaulR BTW if you start writing an answer, post it unfinished by mistake and start getting downvotes, you can delete it, to stop getting the downvotes; edit; then undelete it. your suggestion of 30-seconds delay seems fine to me as well.

Comment: @WillNess: yes, good point - I've used that trick before when I've initially misunderstood a question and then had to revise my answer to match the question.

Comment: Reopening this as the target is closed and can't accept new answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't posted links to your answers that were downvoted so quickly, so this is more general:

Personally, I happen to agree with Doorknob:

> Don't post an answer until you're finished writing it.

I'd even go further to say that you shouldn't post an answer until you are largely satisfied with it - don't hit `Post Your Answer` until it would be acceptable to you if you had to leave it on the site for the rest of the day. Then edit and fine-tune as needed.

But here the general view is far from fixed or agreed upon as you can see in the discussion of the [Fastest Gun in the West Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9731/213634).

The [currently most upvoted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9758/213634) very clearly states that the quick answer should not be discouraged, while [Sam Haslers answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9745/213634) is a little more nuanced. Generally, this question holds a good discussion and a lot of valid viewpoints on the quick answers.

In essence: If you are going for being the fastest gun, you should be prepared for a swift response if your first shot is not spot on.

Comment: Thanks - good answer - I'm making this the accepted answer now as it's a fair summary of the issues and is more constructive than the other answers and comments.

Answer (score 23):

Don't post an answer until you're finished writing it. If an answer is wrong, it should be downvoted. It can then be undownvoted when it is fixed.

Also, this will prevent downvoting "Click this link to speed up your PC for free no viruses I promise" for a minute.

> I'm not advocating for removing down-voting - just having a short time-out after posting/editing before voting can be applied. Perhaps 1 minute is too long though - maybe 30 seconds ?

If it only takes you thirty seconds to fix your post, then do it before pressing the "post answer" button. You say that it would only take you thirty seconds to notice the errors, so spend those thirty seconds before you post, not after it's already officially an answer.

> sometimes due to human fallibility an answer that is still being refined in its infancy can receive premature down-votes

If it is still being refined, **don't post it!** I don't think *you'd* like it if I answered your question with an unfinished answ

Comment: -1 for taking the mickey out of th

Comment: Heh - well in a perfect world of course we'd all spot our mistakes before posting and there would not even be a need for an edit button. Also I think the kind of trigger-happy drive-by down-voters who don't even stop long enough to leave a comment are unlikely to check back later to see if the answer has been fixed and remove their down-votes.

Comment: @Paul Typically if the mistake is not obvious, someone will comment, and then you can fix it.

Comment: @Paul R Stack Overflow gets 7,000+ new questions every day, most of which obviously low-quality ones which do *not* get edited into shape after posting. One of the most important ways to sort the wheat from the chaff is downvoting. The responsibility is on the asker to provide a decent quality question from the get go, period.

Comment: @not Pekka: I'm talking specifically about *answers* here.

Comment: @Paul the same principle applies to answers. Do not post an answer before it looks decent overall. Very few people are going to downvote for small errors... and even if the downvoting were unfair in *your* specific case here, your suggestion would take away the *only* quality control measure we have for answers.

Comment: @PaulR It is not the responsibility of the reader to assume that you're going to fix all of the errors in your answer and to take that account when voting.  They have every right to vote on an answer based on what's there, and if what's there has errors or mistakes, downvoting is almost certainly appropriate.  If your answer isn't ready to be judged by readers then don't post it; it's that simple.

Comment: I'm not advocating for removing down-voting - just having a short time-out after posting/editing before voting can be applied. Perhaps 1 minute is too long though - maybe 30 seconds ?

Comment: @PaulR If it only takes you thirty seconds to fix your post, then do it before pressing the "post answer" button.

Comment: As an aside: for spam, some say [one should only flag, not downvote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193916/why-shouldnt-i-downvote-spam-that-ive-already-flagged). (Though I think that, even if true, such would [only apply to spam *questions* then](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193916/why-shouldnt-i-downvote-spam-that-ive-already-flagged#comment608463_193917).)

Comment: @Doorknob: sure - if I were infallible, as you clearly are, then I would only ever post perfectly polished answers and would have no use for the edit button.

Comment: @PaulR Well, you say that it would only take you thirty seconds to notice the errors. Spend those thirty seconds *before you post*, not after it's already there.

Comment: Ok - you win - too much harshness and aggression in all the responses for me - I don't think I've seen one constructive comment so far - I'll delete the question and you can all go and find someone else to rip apart.

Comment: @PaulR We're not saying you should be perfect, merely that you should accept the responsibility for your mistakes and realize that when they do happen in your posts, downvotes are the *appropriate* response, and you should be glad that the problems are caught by readers, thus improving the site's overall quality, rather than being mad at someone else for correctly responding to a mistake you've made.  Don't be mad at others for voting, be mad at yourself for making the mistake, and let it motivate you to avoid such mistakes going forward.

Comment: @PaulR I don't think I've been at all harsh so far. Mind saying why you think I'm being "aggressive?" I'm simply trying to explain to you how to solve your problem of early downvotes. (by the way, you can't delete this since it has upvoted answers)

Comment: @PaulR, both the downvotes that you complain about, and the answers here, are feedback. Writing *"I don't think I've seen one constructive comment so far"* makes me think you're not quite open for such feedback.

Comment: You're right about not being able to delete the question - I've flagged it and asked a moderator to take care of it, since there doesn't seem to be any value in retaining what has quickly become and all-on-to-one flame-fest.

Comment: @PaulR I don't see a "flame-fest" - I see an orderly discussion. Why do you feel the need to delete this? Someone may have the same idea and see that it has already been declined.

Comment: @PaulR I certainly hope that flag gets declined. The community disagreeing with the premise of your post or the validity of your request does not constitute a flame-fest. If you're not open for input from the community, simply keep your ideas to yourself.

Comment: @PaulR What I'm trying to say is that if the answer is still being refined, **don't post it!** Bart is simply suggesting that if you do not wish to learn why this is a good/bad idea, then don't post it here at all.

Comment: @PaulR But the downvotes *aren't* premature.  The post is wrong, voting on it right then is *entirely appropriate*.  It would be premature if they voted on the post without actually reading it, i.e. downvoting it because something in the first paragraph seemed wrong but that you addressed in the second paragraph.  That isn't the case here.  The post in question is, by your own admission, wrong, so a downvote is entirely justified.

Comment: @PaulR your posts apparently takes the point of view that the downvotes, certainly without comment, are wrong and should not be cast, or be prevented from casting. While in actual fact it's simply your answer that's wrong. If you want to address the issue that voters don't come back to revised questions, address it. (If that's not a dupe) But don't make it sound as if they are wrong in the first place.

Comment: Does this mean that one needs to answer carefully also?? Although my answer has served to help me on the same problem that was being asked.

Taking into consideration the people who gets out of the wrongs side of bed, the serial down voters and the strategic voters, does this mean that the online community has gone from being a helping hand into a critiquing group, who lash out at spelling mistakes and answers that do not suit them?

Comment: And the reversal is yours ;)

Comment: @hims056 :D My second golden shiny on meta!

Comment: @StBlade Yes, you *do* need to answer carefully.  Serially downvoting is addressed, and you're welcome to flag *that* if you suspect you are the victim of it.  Beyond that, if you're posting careless answers without taking the time to ensure that they're correct, clear, and helpful, then you will get downvotes.  That's A Good Thing as it's the primary mechanism to ensure quality content.  If you aren't interested in providing quality content then this isn't the site for you.

Comment: @Servy. Thanks I think I am starting to get a picture. What if part of an answer may just provide someone with maybe needed clarity on answering their own question?  Does it still merit down votes because it does only partially answer the question?  Maybe the one asking the question should have a larger say in the votes, because he will know if the provided answer will solve his question.

Comment: @StBlade If it provides some good information but still doesn't answer the question then you should be posting it as a comment, rather than an answer.  Downvoting a comment posted as an answer is entirely appropriate.

Comment: @Servy. True. I would also want the best answer to my question. Problem is how to differentiate between one persons view on an answer being a comment and another persons view on it being an acceptable answer. Individuals will always have different views, does rating one's more acceptable than another's make it better or does it come down to Mass/Crowd Psychology. Just wondering...

Comment: @StBlade Well, you just said yourself that it doesn't answer the question, it just provides a helpful hint that leads the OP to come up with an answer.  So you yourself don't think it's an answer.  In the case where people disagree on the issue, votes are there in part to help resolve it.  If someone feels that your information doesn't qualify as an answer they'll downvote the post.  If they think it's a sufficient answer, and also of sufficient quality, they'll upvote.  That's the whole idea of the site.

Answer (score 14):

I've downvoted you due to your suggestion (remember votes at Meta are also (mostly) disagree/agree, not just poor quality etc) :

> disallow down-voting (or perhaps any voting ?) until, say, 1 minute after an answer has been posted or last edited ?

The problem with this is you are wanting to introduce a strict blanket policy which may well be fine for that scenario where someone is editing their answer to improve it, but what about the likely majority of scenarios (80+%) where it's just a poor question without code or explanation, or bad answer with no help, code or completely wrong?

I don't want to be bookmarking or remembering to come back somewhere to downvote when someone posted absolute nonsense, or even if I just don't agree (etc).

And, importantly, neither will most people, so it will break the system as it is - votes signify right away if something is good or bad.
There will always be people trying to get badges so "some" votes are not accurate, and people got out of the wrong side of bed, etc. This is unavoidable on an online community.

However, from what I've seen, the system works pretty well as it is. Most answers and questions upvoted or downvotes tend to 95%+ be for a reason.

Comment: you're mistaken: downvotes of this magnitude on meta get a user branded "low quality contributor" very quickly, *automatically* banned from ever being able to raise their voice again (i.e. ask new questions) on meta. Speaking from my own permanently scarred personal experience.

Comment: @WillNess: thanks for the heads up - I didn't know about auto-banning - I'll stick to answering technical questions on SO et al for now and leave meta to the cabal. Clearly outsiders are not welcome.

Comment: I think WillNess is a little exaggerating here. You have good Meta contribution otherwise, and one or two questions where the community disagrees with you isn't going to get you banned. The thing about downvotes is that it's been discussed to death here. Don't let this question here discourage you from further participation though, @PaulR

Comment: "outsiders are not welcome" - define outsiders. In fact, define "insiders". What are they?? I post here, some people donwvoted me, some people upvoted me. I gathered some rep, remember a few names. Does that make me an "insider"? Could I say I'm part of some "thing" you're not welcome to? I'm no different to you, people have disagreed with me plenty. So am I some kind of outsider too? You shouldn't feel bad about people not agreeing with you, some will, some wont. It's a public community where the majority are professionally minded, and everyone has different views and opinions, which is good.

Comment: @slhck exaggerating **what**? come see my two not-so-heavily ***"disagreed-with"*** proposals. I was auto-banned **immediately** after the most recent one. If you guess that I'm mad as hell about it, you're probably not too far from the truth. And if you don't care, then more power to you.

Comment: @slhck another thing is, no-one knows what will get you banned. It's a Kafkian thing. People with power are so full of htemselves, they won;t even tell you what your crimes are when they judge you. Heck, they leave it to an *automaton* to judge you. A criminal at least has their habeas corpus. But not here.

Comment: @WillNess No, I understand you, and I'm not a big proponent of the question ban on Meta either. Scaring people away on the other hand also isn't nice. I wonder if you've already tried contacting the team over this? The q-ban on Meta should be reserved for very extreme cases, not for oppressing opinion.

Comment: @slhck no I didn't try to contact the team. I tried once, on a matter that was of grave concern to me and all (I thought), and when I also raised it on meta that question received *tons* of downvotes and got deleted from the pages of history. AFAIK it even influenced the site design (I'm not sure), but it got me the deleted question under my belt. Two more downvoted Qs a year or so later and I was suddenly banned.

Comment: @WillNess That was a gravatar related issue if I recall correctly? You can always request to have it disassociated from you if you wish to do so.

Comment: @Bart yes; and no, I want it *reinstated* into the historical record - undeleted that is. And I don't accept it being valid grounds for banning anyone. I had a legitimate concern; I still have it. Just I was silenced on the matter, quite violently. -- And BTW few months *after* that whole debacle I noticed an option for a user to upload their own identicon instead; I wonder whether my question has facilitated that change (or did it exist before and I just didn't know about it?). And if so, then that Q was certainly ***helpful*** to the site and I should be ***rewarded*** for it.

Comment: @WillNess People have had the ability to upload their own avatar for a *long* time, I believe since the beginning.

Comment: @Servy do you mean a specific SE avatar, or on Gravatar itself. Because I knew about the latter option, and it was very cumbersome.

Comment: @WillNess I'm talking about on SE.

Comment: @Servy I didn't know about that. Thanks. That invalidates my previous comment. My raising that Q changed nothing, then.

Comment: @Servy but if I may, one more question: was it done as easily as it is now, by just hovering above the avatar on a user page?

Comment: @WillNess As you can see from my profile, I've never changed my picture.  I'm pretty sure it was a different UI at some point, but I'm not sure when it changed, if at all.  I know there was an option for it on people's profiles for quite some time though.

Comment: @Servy thanks. You were lucky enough with that picture.

Comment: @Servy AFAICR, I had to go through Gravatar itself to change *my* picture on SO. It was a cumbersome process that would take up to a whole day to take effect there and propagate back here. So an easy and immediate UI *is* a big deal, IMO.