# Votes and downvotes don't line up

Tags: bug, down-votes, views

We just got a spammy post ([here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244364)) and I'm confused by the view / vote counter:

[image]

This was *after* a refresh - I saw it, though what!?, refreshed and it stayed...

I this due to the weird behaviour of the vote counter? It is worse than it seems - vote 1 is the OP and they can't have downvoted their post, so the view counter is off by at least 2...

Comment: ... and on a sidenote, please read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193916/why-shouldnt-i-downvote-spam-that-ive-already-flagged) and adapt your practice accordingly.

Comment: @rene yes, someone said that and I was just searching for it! Ta.