# I issued my first flag and got a deduction for it

Tags: support, reputation, flags, spam

As my title says, it was the first time I had issued a flag. There was this answer to one of my questions that clearly was spam. It was a clear advertising of a website/application and in no way answers or even relates to my question, and it was from a new contributor.

I flagged it as a spam and shortly after I got a notification of a -1 reputation. When I clicked the notification it brought me to the "answer" I had just flagged.

I thought I was helping maintain the quality of answers on this site by doing this, and to get a deduction (even a meager -1 reputation) was pretty discouraging. Did I really just get a deduction from flagging? I read the different flags carefully and am absolutely sure it's spam.

Comment: Note for other visitors: The answer was to [this](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/49550/how-did-people-in-the-desert-stay-cool-in-the-past) question and has been deleted now.

Comment: You should get your reputation back soon, unless it had nothing to do with the spam answer.

Comment: yes, the spam is gone now. quite quickly too.
i suppose it is a duplicate, it does answer mine. I thought it was from flagging not from downvoting though. Still, my mistake

Answer (score 11):

No, flagging doesn't cost you [reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/295232). *Downvoting* an answer costs you 1 reputation, and a spam flag carries an *automatic* downvote, but that one doesn't cost reputation; it's even possible to spam flag *and* downvote an answer. That is most likely what you have done. Don't worry, when the answer is removed, you'll get that 1 reputation back a few minutes later.

It's not really useful to downvote spam, but in most cases not harmful either, see
[Why shouldn't I downvote spam that I've already flagged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193916/295232)

Comment: Ah I see, so it was from downvoting the answer. I've downvoted questions before and usually only have given upvotes to answers, since answers i've come across were all sensible. Thanks.